# Помогите с написанием запроса SQL

Tags: sql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
знаю, что здесь нужно использовать left join, но не знаю, как в итоговую таблицу получить имя клиента, на которого ссылается текущий клиент

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT i.*,c.Name as Customer_Name,r.Name as Reffered_Name FROM Invoices i LEFT JOIN Customers c ON (i.Customer_ID=c.id) LEFT JOIN Customers r ON (c.Reffered_ID=r.id)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: например расписать как работает LEFT JOIN ?

Comment: нет, написать в двух словах «как в итоговую таблицу получить имя клиента, на которого ссылается текущий клиент».